# SQL redshift - filter table by specific criteria but for rows that don't have that criteria return the max value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, filtering

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

Im trying to remove duplicate `ID` based on the code column. I would like to return all ID's that have a code `Y`, even if the `ID` appears more than once. For ID's that don't have a `Y`, I would like to return only the max amount from `Amount` for the other Codes (can be any code as long as its the max amount and only one amount is required). The final table should look like this:

[image]

I've tried using the following code but I end up returning only `ID` records with `Y`:

```
select *
from 
    my_tbl
where exists (
        select 
            max(Amount) as Amount
        from 
            my_tbl
        where 
            Code <> 'Y'
        )
and Code = 'Y'
group by ID, Date
order by ID, Date
;
```

Is there a solution to filter my table this way?

Comment: Write one query for the Y records, another for the non-Y records and union the two results together

Comment: hi @NickW thank you for your reply. Not sure if it's my query that's causing the issue, but the union method didn't quite get the results i needed. I noticed that some ID's that had both ```Y``` and ```non-Y``` records for a given day would be returned together. Ideally what i would like to see is only the ```Y``` record been returned and only return a ```non-Y``` record if that ID did not have a ```Y``` record.

Comment: I think the issue is when I bring in the ```Code``` field into the table, it is recognising it as two distinct records even though it is the same ```ID``` and the same day, but as it has both ```Y``` and ```non-Y``` codes, it is pulling both rows into the table as two separate records - which isn't wrong but not the result i'm after. I can solve this by removing the ```Code``` column, but i would like to keep this in the table for other analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the row_number() window function to mark the max value per ID but use a case (decode) to bring rows with CODE ‘Y’ to the top.  Something like:

```
select id, “date”, code, amount 
from (
  select id, “date”, code, amount,
  row_number() over (partition by id order by
    decode(code,’Y’,9999999999,amount) desc) rn
  from my_tbl
  where rn = 1
)
order by “date”
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
WITH w_rn AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , CASE NVL(code,'')
      WHEN 'Y' THEN 1
      ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY id
        ORDER BY amount DESC
      )
    END AS rn
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
 *
FROM w_rn
WHERE rn=1
ORDER BY id,date
;
-- out  ID |    Date    | Code | Amount | rn 
-- out ----+------------+------+--------+----
-- out   1 | 2022-11-30 | Y    |     50 |  1
-- out   2 | 2022-12-01 |      |  10000 |  1
-- out   3 | 2022-12-01 | Y    |     50 |  1
-- out   3 | 2022-12-01 | Y    |    100 |  1
-- out   4 | 2022-12-03 | B    |   3000 |  1
-- out   5 | 2022-12-05 | C    |   2000 |  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should give you what you want:

```
-- Select all Y records
with y_records as (
    select *
    from mytable1 t1
    where code = 'Y'
),
-- Select all non-Y records
non_y_records as (
    select *
    from mytable1 t3
    where  code != 'Y' or code is null
),
-- For non-Y records get the record(s) with the max value for each date
non_y_records_max as (
    select nony1.*
    from non_y_records nony1
    where nony1.amount = (select max(nony2.amount) 
                       from non_y_records nony2
                       where nony1.tx_date = nony2.tx_date)
)
select id, tx_date, code, amount
from y_records t5
union
select id, tx_date, code, amount
from non_y_records_max t6
-- Get only one record per date - arbitrarily selecting the one with the max code value
-- Use NVL to default the code to X if it is null to make the comparison simpler
where nvl(t6.code,'X') = nvl((select max(t7.code) 
                   from non_y_records_max t7 
                   where t6.tx_date = t7.tx_date),'X')
order by tx_date, code
;
```